# Is it fraud to receive coronavirus mortgage relief when you left your job for non-COVID reasons, such as a divorce?

Tags: covid-19

A person quits their job non-COVID related reasons. The person moves out of the state and abandoned the home. During that time, this person makes a request to receive COVID relief on their mortgage.

Is this illegal? Also does the spouse have a legal obligation to report it?

Comment: There are quite a lot of COVID-related mortgage-relief programs, and the answer may depend on which one is involved. Which program, specifically, are you talking about?

Comment: Said individual could say they could not find a job in their new locale because the economy tanked. Or because the kiddo can’t go to school.  The program really only says “pandemic related financial hardship.” Mixing divorce/custody dispute and some unrelated law the other party is purportedly violating rarely helps..

Comment: Your question is very unclear and poorly written, not to mention the multitude of gaps that make it unanswerable. Who do you mean by "*they*"? what do you mean by a person [in singular] quitting "their" [in plural] job? whose spouse are you asking about?

Comment: I'm not sure which mortgage-relief program.
The person is a nurse and has not experienced any difficulty finding a job.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Assuming you meant USA

No. The criteria are so vague that it can include almost anything, like cannot find a new job because everything is down, extra expenses, etc:

> For homeowners with mortgages covered by the CARES Act, you only need to explain that you have a pandemic-related financial hardship, directly or **indirectly** related to the pandemic.

(Emphasis added)

[CFPB](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/coronavirus/mortgage-and-housing-assistance/request-forbearance-or-mortgage-relief///)

As noted in a comment by @bdb484, there are different programs, so it might depend which one and which relief.